# referencing the latest state in useInterval that uses useRef

Tags: reactjs

[As Dan Abramov introduced](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/), I wrote an interval using useRef so it does not get created on every render. My code below saves the redux store into local storage every 20 seconds. However, the `store` inside of `setInterval` does not get updated which leads to saving the same initial store every 20 seconds.

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import styles from "./AutoSaveButton.module.scss";
import LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY from "../../../constants/localStorage";

const TWO_SECONDS = 2000;
const TWENTY_SECONDS = 20000;

function AutoSaveButton() {
  const store = useSelector((state) => state);

  const interval = useRef(null);

  const [isAutoSaveOn, setIsAutoSaveOn] = useState(false);
  const [isSavedMsgDisplayed, setIsSavedMsgDisplayed] = useState(false);

  const toggleAutoSave = () => {
    if (isAutoSaveOn) {
      setIsAutoSaveOn(false);
      clearInterval(interval.current);
      return;
    }

    setIsAutoSaveOn(true);

    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(store)); <-- how to update?
      setIsSavedMsgDisplayed(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsSavedMsgDisplayed(false);
      }, TWO_SECONDS);
    }, TWENTY_SECONDS);
  };

  return (
    <span
      className={isAutoSaveOn ? styles.active : styles.stale}
      onClick={toggleAutoSave}
    >
      {isAutoSaveOn ? "auto save off" : "auto save on"}
      {isAutoSaveOn && (
        <span
          className={`material-symbols-outlined ${
            isSavedMsgDisplayed ? styles["icon-visible"] : styles["icon-greyed"]
          }`}
        >
          done
        </span>
      )}
    </span>
  );
}

export default AutoSaveButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since closure will always capture the variable store each time it's reinitialized. use **[YOUR STORE].getState().[your reducer]** instead

```js
const { useRef, useState } = React
const { useSelector,Provider,useDispatch } = ReactRedux
const { configureStore,createSlice } = window.RTK

//import styles from "./AutoSaveButton.module.scss";
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "XXX"


const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'data',
  initialState: {
    value: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    setData: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload
    },
  },
})
const mystore=configureStore({
  reducer: {
    data: slice.reducer
    },
})

const TWO_SECONDS = 2000;
const TWENTY_SECONDS = 20000;

function AutoSaveButton() {
  const store = useSelector((state) => state.data);

  const interval = useRef(null);

  const [isAutoSaveOn, setIsAutoSaveOn] = useState(false);
  const [isSavedMsgDisplayed, setIsSavedMsgDisplayed] = useState(false);

  const toggleAutoSave = (store) => {
    if (isAutoSaveOn) {
      setIsAutoSaveOn(false);
      clearInterval(interval.current);
      return;
    }

    setIsAutoSaveOn(true);
    console.log("store outside", store);

    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
     
      setIsSavedMsgDisplayed(true);
      console.log("store inside", mystore.getState().data);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsSavedMsgDisplayed(false);
      }, TWO_SECONDS);
       //localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(mystore.getState().data)); //<-- how to update?
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <span
      className=""
      onClick={()=>toggleAutoSave(store)}
    >
      {isAutoSaveOn ? "auto save off" : "auto save on"}
      {isAutoSaveOn && (
        <span
          className={`material-symbols-outlined `}
        >
          done
        </span>
      )}
    </span>
  );
}
const App=()=>{

return <Provider store={mystore}>
    <AutoSaveButton />
    <B/>
  </Provider>
}
const B=()=>{
const dispatch=useDispatch()
return <button onClick={()=>dispatch(slice.actions.setData(12))}>
    setData
    </button>
    }
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("App"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/8.0.2/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reduxjs/toolkit@1.8.3/dist/redux-toolkit.umd.js"></script>
<div id="App">
</div>
```

second way watchc store with useEffect and put it to ref

```js
const { useRef, useState, useEffect} = React
const { useSelector,Provider,useDispatch } = ReactRedux
const { configureStore,createSlice } = window.RTK

//import styles from "./AutoSaveButton.module.scss";
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "XXX"


const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'data',
  initialState: {
    value: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    setData: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload
    },
  },
})
const mystore=configureStore({
  reducer: {
    data: slice.reducer
    },
})

const TWO_SECONDS = 2000;
const TWENTY_SECONDS = 20000;

function AutoSaveButton() {
  const store = useSelector((state) => state.data);

  const interval = useRef(null);
  const mystore = useRef(store);
  useEffect(()=>{
    mystore.current=store
  },[store])
  
  const [isAutoSaveOn, setIsAutoSaveOn] = useState(false);
  const [isSavedMsgDisplayed, setIsSavedMsgDisplayed] = useState(false);

  const toggleAutoSave = () => {
    if (isAutoSaveOn) {
      setIsAutoSaveOn(false);
      clearInterval(interval.current);
      return;
    }

    setIsAutoSaveOn(true);
    console.log("store outside", store);

    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
     
      setIsSavedMsgDisplayed(true);
      console.log("store inside", mystore.current);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsSavedMsgDisplayed(false);
      }, TWO_SECONDS);
       //localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(mystore.current); //<-- how to update?
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <span
      className=""
      onClick={toggleAutoSave}
    >
      {isAutoSaveOn ? "auto save off" : "auto save on"}
      {isAutoSaveOn && (
        <span
          className={`material-symbols-outlined `}
        >
          done
        </span>
      )}
    </span>
  );
}
const App=()=>{

return <Provider store={mystore}>
    <AutoSaveButton />
    <B/>
  </Provider>
}
const B=()=>{
const dispatch=useDispatch()
return <button onClick={()=>dispatch(slice.actions.setData(12))}>
    setData
    </button>
    }
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("App"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/8.0.2/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reduxjs/toolkit@1.8.3/dist/redux-toolkit.umd.js"></script>
<div id="App">
</div>
```

Comment: Nailed it man. I didn't think of using store.getState() inside of the interval.. Thanks for advice!

Comment: actually the correct way is using useeffect and then use new variable useref that holding current store

Comment: Could you share the code for the sake of others visiting here for similar cases?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer myself, but if any of you find this dumb, please leave a comment. I am open to discussions!

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import styles from "./AutoSaveButton.module.scss";
import LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY from "../../../constants/localStorage";

const TWO_SECONDS = 2000;
const TWENTY_SECONDS = 5000;

function AutoSaveButton() {
  const store = useSelector((state) => state);

  const interval = useRef(null);

  const [isAutoSaveOn, setIsAutoSaveOn] = useState(false);
  const [isSavedMsgDisplayed, setIsSavedMsgDisplayed] = useState(false);

  const toggleAutoSave = () => {
    if (isAutoSaveOn) {
      setIsAutoSaveOn(false);
      clearInterval(interval.current);
      return;
    }

    setIsAutoSaveOn(true);

    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(store));
      setIsSavedMsgDisplayed(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsSavedMsgDisplayed(false);
      }, TWO_SECONDS);
    }, TWENTY_SECONDS);
  };

  /* I added below useEffect and got desired result! */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!interval.current) return;

    clearInterval(interval.current);

    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(store));
      setIsSavedMsgDisplayed(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsSavedMsgDisplayed(false);
      }, TWO_SECONDS);
    }, TWENTY_SECONDS);
  }, [store]);

  return (
    <span
      className={isAutoSaveOn ? styles.active : styles.stale}
      onClick={toggleAutoSave}
    >
      {isAutoSaveOn ? "auto save off" : "auto save on"}
      {isAutoSaveOn && (
        <span
          className={`material-symbols-outlined ${
            isSavedMsgDisplayed ? styles["icon-visible"] : styles["icon-greyed"]
          }`}
        >
          done
        </span>
      )}
    </span>
  );
}

export default AutoSaveButton;
```

Comment: thats makes each time store updated setInterval will recreated again and over again thats why store inside that setInterval always present